# Upgrade SQL Server 2000 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In our project we are using sql server 2000 databases and we are planning to move to sql server 2012  can anyone tell me waht are the specific issues should i face in the programming and queries point of view? Whats changes should be necessary in script?

Comment: [Deprecated features in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) (also, the Other versions drop down allows you to see the 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 versions). Then take all of those and comb your code base looking for them.

Comment: i know but tell me the changes which i should to convert sql server 2000 to 2012. one thing i notice that joins syntax of sql 2000 is different from sql 2012.. but i want to know all guidelines. which is necessary for those.. u understand?

Comment: You're asking an unanswerable question - we have no idea what code you have and what changes you'll have to make. There's not a "one-size fits all" answer here - it very much depends on which features you're using. It can't be answered on a Q+A site - it needs someone to take time to familiarise themselves with the current code base and then, based on the above pages I mentioned, work out what changes are required.

Comment: I agree with you but some of most common guideline which used to convert sql 2000 to sql 2012.. To follow this guideline your data will not be changed and u can easily be converted.. as above i ll tell u "join operators"

Answer (score 0):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever has mentioned, the proper way to do this is to look through the deprecated features of each version since 2000 (2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012) and see if your code uses any of them. Also as mentioned, you can find those features here:

[Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

Check each version's deprecated feature page as they are not cumulative.

I would use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to script out the current database code to see what is affected (right-click DB -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts). You will also need to check your application code if you have in-line queries.

As an example, if you're using non-ansi outer join operators like `*=` or `=*` then you will want to update those queries, as these are no longer supported in 2012.

I suppose you could even run the generated script in 2012 to see what throws exceptions.

I would suggest that you test your applications thoroughly no matter how you upgrade.

PS: I know this question is old, but I think it's still plenty relevant.